# Using git-bash with visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I normally use git-bash.exe on Windows 10 but visual studio code seems to use bash.exe.  bash.exe seems very limited :(

I am trying to either get bash.exe to be more useful or get git-bash.exe to run in the terminal at the bottom of the screen.

Any suggestions?

```
    // this opens the terminal window at the bottom of code
    // but as I said, seems limited.
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    }

    // the problem with this is it opens a new window when
    // run and I would prefer it be at the bottom.
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    },
```

Comment: Can you not dock the new window at the bottom of the VS Code window?

Comment: does not seem to be an option, wondering if there is another command I can add.  Not sure why it is popping out in the first place

Comment: Have you tried this? `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`  Found it on this site: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: @MichaelPlatt -- that was sort of the point, if I use that it works but that version of bash is very limited.  git-bash is much more useful but pops out.

Comment: Ah oops.  Misread the text in the article.  My mistake.